# Dividing a NumPy array by another NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array `x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 6, 8]])`, and I want to divide every element by `y`. However, `y` is not a single number, but an array, `y = np.array([2, 4])`. I want to divide each row of `x` by each row of `y`, to return `np.array([[0.5, 1.0, 1.5], [1.0, 1.5, 2.0])`.

How can I do this? If I just run `x / y`, I get an error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (2,)`

Comment: .. `x/y[:,None]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations between multiple arrays must follow numpy's [broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Here, your second array has to be reshaped to shape `(2, 1)` either via

```
x / y.reshape(2, 1)
```

or equivalently

```
x / y[:, np.newaxis]
```